# delay time on UIImageView

Tags: swift, swipe-gesture

i have array of image when i send the index of image from collectionView to another viewController which is display this image in full screen and i give the user ability to swipe between images but the issue on the swipe 
the swipe between images when change it is very fast i need to delay time on UIImageView when the image is changed any solution on that issue ?

the code below:

```
var ImageIndex:Int = 0 // this is index image which i send it from previous view controller
var arrayOfUrlImageLarge:[String] = []// this array which contain all the url of images
```

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
```

imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(contentsOfFile:         arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex]))

```
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

     let swipeGestureRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ShowImageViewController.swipe(_:)))
    swipeGestureRight.direction = .Right
    let swipeGestureLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ShowImageViewController.swipe(_:)))
    swipeGestureLeft.direction = .Left
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureLeft)
    self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRight)
 }
```

func swipe(gesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

```
    if gesture.direction == .Right {

        if ImageIndex == 0 {
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)
        }else {
            ImageIndex = ImageIndex - 1
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)
        }
    }
    if gesture.direction == .Left{

        if ImageIndex >= arrayOfUrlImageLarge.count {
            ImageIndex = arrayOfUrlImageLarge.count - 1
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)
        }else {
            ImageIndex = ImageIndex + 1
            if ImageIndex >= arrayOfUrlImageLarge.count {
                return
            }
            imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)

        }
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
func swipe(gesture:UISwipeGestureRecognizer){

   let delay = 4.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
   let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
   dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

       if gesture.direction == .Right {

        if ImageIndex == 0 {
           imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)
        }
        else {
          ImageIndex = ImageIndex - 1
          imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)
        }
       }
      if gesture.direction == .Left{

        if ImageIndex >= arrayOfUrlImageLarge.count {
           ImageIndex = arrayOfUrlImageLarge.count - 1
           imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)
       }
       else {
         ImageIndex = ImageIndex + 1
         if ImageIndex >= arrayOfUrlImageLarge.count {
            return
         }
        imageView.image = UIImage(data: NSData(contentsOfFile: arrayOfUrlImageLarge[ImageIndex])!)
        }

      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much please where i put this method in viewdidload?

Comment: try in the same method

Comment: check the updated answer it will execute after the duration

Comment: in the comment animation what am doing ? fade?

Comment: you dont need to animate anything.